# Where should I put my ressources when doing an app with angular + .net Core

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular, .net-core

I'm experience Asp.Net Core + Angular, I've set up a project(through `dotnet new angular`) and started to apply my admin theme.

Currently I've put all my theme resources directly in the wwwroot/dist folder:
[image]

I'm encountering an issue:

In my app.component.html I use one of the resource(one logo):

`<img src="dist/img/logo.png" alt="J4N Logo" class="brand-icon">`

then I get an error from angular:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: Error:
>   Cannot find module "./dist/img/logo.png"

I understand that is because angular try to load this itself and think this may be some controllers of some sort. The thing is, this kind of logo/css/... could be also used even before the angular app is started(e.g. in the loading page), so I cannot put this in the angular app folder.

So what is the best practice, where should I put this kind of files and how should I tell angular to look elsewhere?+

Comment: Can you try `~/dist/img/logo.png`

Comment: @George, tried, but it gives the same exact error message

Answer (score 0):

Put it in your wwwroot folder. Your dist folder will get replaced when compiled while wwwroot folder is IIS wwwroot folder equivalent. If you put it like below:

```
wwwroot/
       www.example.com // your website, aka dist folder
       assets/
             img/
                01.png
                02.png
```

Then the url to your `01.png` will be `www.example.com/assets/img/01.png`.

[ Edit ]: Just want to add. In your case, get your img **out** of 
**dist** folder and put it into **wwwroot**. then your **src** would be `<img src="/img/logo.png" alt="J4N Logo" class="brand-icon">`.

Comment: I moved my ressources directly in the `wwwroot` folder and changed the url as you proposed, but now I get this: `NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: Error: Cannot find module "./img/logo.png"`

Comment: sorry, can you try `<img src="/img/logo.png" alt="J4N Logo" class="brand-icon">`.

Comment: Are you also using the static files middleware?

Comment: I tried, but same error. I really have the feeling that I should configure something on Angular for him to know it is an asset.

Comment: @JamieTaylor I'm really sorry, but I don't know what is a static file middleware. I've just created a site with the dotnet new angular and started to add theme, nothing else.

Comment: In the Startup class, there will be a method called `Configure`. In that method, the .NET Core middleware are set up (they act as a pipeline for your requests). To enable ASP.NET Core to server static files (i.e. from your wwwroot directory), you'll need to ensure that `app.UseStaticFiles();` is called in that method.

Comment: @JamieTaylor found it, it's called, juste before the UseMvc

Comment: `UseStaticFiles();` should be there by default. You should try:
- access the image via url. i.e: `localhost:5000/assets/img/01.png`. Can you see the image, yes/no?
- create a new project `mkdir test-proj`, `cd test-proj`, `dotnet new angular` and try it with the new project.

At this point, you're pretty much on your own to me honest. There is one more thing you can try. That is go into `Index.cshtml` at line 5 where it said `<app asp-prerender-module=".....` put an `x` next to asp like `<app xasp-prerender...` to disable it and see. Since, it mentioned prerendering.

Comment: @lock22 you can short circuit the mkdir command by adding `-- name` and a name to the end of the `dotnet new` command.

Comment: @lock22 If I go to http://localhost:50113/img/logo.png, I get the image. it seems it's just angular that doesn't know that it is an image and not an angular path.

Comment: @J4N If you're really attached to this project and haven't figured it out. Let me have a look at your repo. Other wise, just create a new project. I've just created a `dotnet new angular` project, `npm install`, `dotnet restore` then add `assets/img/01.png` to `wwwroot` folder and add `<img src="/assets/img/01.jpg" alt="">` to `home.component.html` and it displays the image without any problem.

Comment: I also tried to put it in the wwwroot/assets/img/logo without any luck. One difference with you is that the logo is in the app.component.html, before the exact controller. I just put the current status on https://github.com/jgrossrieder/AngularStart . I'm curious about what you find

Comment: Your issue was, you didn't **replace all of the src**. You got blocks for small screen as well. You need to apply the correct url to the images for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an assets folder named "assets" for example under ClientApp folder and put your ressources here.

Comment: But this would prevent using it outside of the angular app(e.g. from the loading page of the angular page.